# How can I use the same style on several TextBlock controls, but have each control using different bindings and triggers?

Tags: xaml, triggers, styles

I'd like to have several TextBlocks generally looking the same, but each needs to react on another trigger and in another way. I've tried to use a common style (MyTextBlockStyle) and add triggers later. But I get allways error meesages like "the property 'style' has been declared twice" or simillar.

To explain what I mean, I've made an example with 3 TextBlocks. 2 of them are bound to each a different CheckBox, and each triggering a different property (displayed text vs. foreground color). A third TextBlock shall change its background color depending of the content of a TextbBox. How can I achieve something like this?

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
        </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid >
        <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox01" Content="Change Background of TextBlock 1" IsChecked="False" Foreground="White" Margin="5" />
            <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox02" Content="Change Background of TextBlock 2" IsChecked="False" Foreground="White" Margin="5" />
            <TextBox x:Name="TextBox03" Padding="10" Background="White" Text="Enter Text here ..." Tooltip="Change Background of TextBlock 3"/>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockStyle}" >
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="No" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=CheckBox01, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Yes!" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Style="{Static Resource MyTextBlockStyle}" Text="Something different">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=CheckBox02, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Style="{Static Resource MyTextBlockStyle}" Text="Anything else">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TextBox03, Path=Text}" Value="">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
</Grid >
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.It works.I guess as you wish

```
  <Window.Resources>       
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">              
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=CheckBox01,Path=IsChecked}" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Tag}" Value="tb1"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="Orange"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=CheckBox02,Path=IsChecked}" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Tag}" Value="tb2"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="Pink"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=TextBox03,Path=Text}" Value=""/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Tag}" Value="tb3"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="Green"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel Margin="10">           
        <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox01" Content="Change Background of TextBlock 1" IsChecked="False"  Margin="5"/>          
        <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox02" Content="Change Background of TextBlock 2" IsChecked="False" Margin="5"/>           
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox03" Padding="10" Background="White" Text="Enter Text here ..."/>           
        <TextBlock Tag="tb1"/>
        <TextBlock Tag="tb2" Text="Something different"/>
        <TextBlock Tag="tb3" x:Name="tb3" Text="Anything else"/>               
    </StackPanel>
</Grid >
```

Comment: Is there only the way using a style then? As these triggers are rather unique each, I was hoping it might be possible to 'modify' the style afterwards within the controls directly, like it would be possible, if I wouldn't use the 'style=' property. Anyway, thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the BasedOn Property.  It gets me all the time.

```
<TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="MyTextBlockStyle">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="No" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=CheckBox01, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Yes!" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
```